# Error with EF core savecontext using Identity class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I have a quiz sql schema and I am also using ASP.NET Identity. When I attempt to insert an answer from the user into the UserAnswer table I get the error below. It seems like it is trying to insert into the User table but I don't want that?

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is
>   (71ddfebf-18ba-4214-a01e-42ca0f239804). Cannot insert explicit value
>   for identity column in table 'Questions' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set
>   to OFF. The statement has been terminated.

```cs
foreach (ProfileViewModel pvm in profileViewModels)
{
    UserAnswer ua = new UserAnswer();

    ua.QuestionId.ID = pvm.Question.ID;
    ua.ApplicationUser.Id = userId;
    ua.AnswerText = pvm.Answer;

    _userAnswerRepository.Create(ua);
}
```

which just does

```cs
protected void Save() => _context.SaveChanges();
```

and the model is

```cs
public class UserAnswer
{
    public UserAnswer()
    {
        this.QuestionId = new Question();
        this.ApplicationUser = new ApplicationUser();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public Question QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess I need to use virtual and not the actual object for some reason.. The model looked fine but it seems to confused the update

```
 public class UserAnswer
{
    public UserAnswer()
    {
        this.Question = new Question();
        this.User = new ApplicationUser();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; } // FK to ApplicationUser
    public int QuestionId { get; set; } // FK to Question
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The key is not the `virtual`, but the explicit FK properties. Also never initialize reference navigation properties with `new ...`

Comment: could this be why I'm getting blank rows in the associated tables when I do an insert ?

Comment: Absolutely! One of the side effects of doing that.